# Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My code is not working, and I am not sure why.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class enemys extends MovieClip {

    public var playz:Circles 

    public function enemys() {

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hittrue)
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moving)

    }

    public function hittrue(event:Event) {


        if (this.hitTestObject(playz)) {

            while (numChildren > 0) {

                removeChildAt(0)
            }

            gotoAndStop(2)
        }

    }

}
```

It has to do with the variable playz: it says it is null yet I defined it in the variable section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a variable which's referencing a `Circles` object, but you did not give it a refernece aka did not instantiate a new `Circles` instance and put it in the `playz` variable.
You should create a new instance and store it in the `playz` variable before you start using it, else you get that error.

```
playz = new Circles();
```